# MAUI System.Data.SQLClient not available on Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

I am stuck at creating a simple SQL Query in C# because VS 2022 keeps saying System.Data.SQLClient is not available inside my Android project.

[image]

When i installed the package separately over NuGet, the outcome did not change.

Comment: It is generally a terrible idea to connect directly to a db server from a mobile client

Comment: That means that there is no implementation available for the `net6.0-android` target framework. Is this package intended for frontend development? To me it seems like it's targeted toward server applications: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: That means that there is no implementation available for the `net6.0-android` target framework. Is this package intended for frontend development? To me it seems like it's targeted toward server applications: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem in my MAUI test app, and I solved it using Microsoft.Data.SQLClient with TrustServerCertificate=true instead of System.Data.SQLClient

Answer (score -2):

To continue using System.Data.SqlClient you can disable targeting of the android platform.

Project>App Properties>Application>Android Targets

Uncheck "Target the Android platform"